# Passing arguments into active threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am currently working on writing a multi threaded web interaction script, for simplicity sake I will not dive into specific details.

My question is this: 
I have multiple threads that are going to log in to a website and wait for a certain data value to become available. This data value is required for each thread to successfully carry out its task. On a single thread I am going to be constantly searching for this value. When the value is found I want to pass it into each of the active threads then have them continue carrying out the rest of their functions.

Note: I need all of the threads to already be active prior to retrieving this data value.

What python threading commands can allow me to do this? I found some reference to threading.condition(); however, I could not find any useful examples of this.

Comment: Take a look at Python threading queue
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  I found some reference to `threading.condition()` however, I could not find any useful examples of this.

Read the example in the following Documentation:

> **Python » 3.6.1 Documentation** [barrier-objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#barrier-objects)
>   This class provides a simple synchronization primitive for use by a fixed number of threads that need to wait for each other.